# For...Next Loop Timing Issue

Tags: vb.net, timing

I have a strange issue with running this loop. It seems to run only once irrespective of the rows which are available in the datatable. But if I put that message box just above the `Next` keyword, the loops starts working as expected. There seems to be some kind of timing issue here. Please guide on how to constrain the loop to work as per the number of rows.
The loop stops at the message box, I click OK and then it runs normally. But if I remove that message box, it seems to run only once.
Just to assure, in the `If` condition, it returns **not equal** in the first iteration and thus the loop is not exiting as per the code!

```
 For CheckShopNames As Integer = 0 To DTShopNameSearch.Rows.Count - 1

            If DTShopNameSearch.Rows(CheckShopNames).Item(1) = txtshop.Text Then
             
                MsgBox(DTShopNameSearch.Rows(CheckShopNames).Item(1))  'FOR TESTING

                SaveFlag = True
                Exit For
            ElseIf DTShopNameSearch.Rows(CheckShopNames).Item(1) <> txtshop.Text Then
                SaveFlag = False
               

            End If
            MsgBox(10)  'FOR TESTING
        Next
```

Comment: Those message boxes were inserted much after I repeatedly tested for the expected results. As a last measure, I inserted those message boxes and found the issue.

Comment: Well you do exit the loop with the "exit for" when your .Item(1) = txtshop.Text. And there is no point in that elseif check, if first is not equals then it's not equal for sure, why you are checking if it's not equal when you already checked if it is equal and it was false idk. if and else is enough, remove elseif.

Comment: When processing collections such as datatable rows, you can save yourself a lot of hassles by using a For Each loop structure rather than this

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see how many times your loop runs. Turn on Option Strict. You are testing for the second column in the DataTable.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim counter = 1
    For Each row As DataRow In DTShopNameSearch.Rows
        If row(1).ToString = txtshop.Text Then 
            MessageBox.Show(row(1).ToString)  'FOR TESTING
            SaveFlag = True
            MessageBox.Show($"I am exiting For loop after {counter} iterations.")
            Exit For
        Else
            SaveFlag = False
        End If
        counter += 1
    Next
    MessageBox.Show($"For loop is done and there were {counter} iterations.")
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Here is an actual test performed on my computer. I changeed the code a bit. There is no reason to repeatedly set the SaveFlag to False. I did not explicitly initialize counter. I used local data and control names.

```
Private SaveFlag As Boolean

Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim dt = LoadCoffeeTable()
    Debug.Print(dt.Rows.Count.ToString)
    Dim counter As Integer
    SaveFlag = False
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows 'DTShopNameSearch.Rows
        counter += 1
        If row(1).ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
            MessageBox.Show(row(1).ToString)  'FOR TESTING
            SaveFlag = True
            MessageBox.Show($"I am exiting For loop after {counter} iterations.")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show($"For loop is done and there were {counter} iterations.")
End Sub

Private Function LoadCoffeeTable() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnection),
           cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Top 10 ID, Name, IsExtraBold, IsFavorite From Coffees", cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

I happen to know that the third row has a Name column that contains "Green". I entered this is TextBox1. The message boxes appeared as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately the above code is also causing the same issue. If I turn on Option Strict, it causes other conflicts in my code, specifically this line: `combobox.SelectedItem(1)` . Please suggest a cure for this!
One more interesting observation is that the above mentioned problem occurs only when the code runs for the first time. When I try the code a second time, it works as expected. Could this be a threading issue?

Comment: Re: `combobox.SelectedItem(1)` Since vb.net is case insensitive you cannot name a `ComboBox` `combobox`. `.SelectedItem` is not a collection so you can't refer to an index. `.SelectedItem` is an object. If you want a string call `.ToString`  `ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString`

Comment: I have no idea why this code is not working for you. Problems with Option Strict On should be fixed in your code. See the EDIT to my code. It runs for me.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion regarding the combobox name. I used that indicatively here. The actual names in the codes are different like `cmbCategory.SelectedItem(1)` which gets me the value of the selected item at index 1 from the combobox datasource. I managed to resolve all other Option Strict On conflicts except this and could not find an online solution to this issue. The exact error is "Option Strict On does not allow late binding". Regarding the misbehaving code, it is very very strange since, as I said, it runs either if a messagebox is introduced or when it runs a second time!!

Comment: I did insert this `DTShopNameSearch.Clear()` above the code to guard against any stray data in the table causing these conflicts. But still no good.

Comment: From the docs "Clear() 
Clears the DataTable of all data." If you clear the data there are no rows.

Comment: OK, my fault that we are going around in circles because I did not provide the complete code. Also a result of the limitations of comments here. Anyway, after clearing the datatable, I load it again using `DAShopNames.Fill(DTShopNameSearch)`. Please show me a way to use that combobox selecteditem(1) method with Option Strict On so I can implement that code. Thanks.

Comment: @KhalidKagzi I think you are confusing a ComboBox and a ListBox. A ListBox has a .SelectionMode property where you can allow more than one selection. It also has a .SelectiedItems property. Note the s on the end (plural) that indicates this is a collection that is indexed. The ComboBox does not have a multi-select mode and .SelectedItem is singular - no collection - no index.